# ES6: constructor can't declare as arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is my React.js component definition:

```
class ExampleComponent1 extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

When webpack this with babel loader, everything would be fine. But then I change the `constructor` declare to arrow function:

```
class ExampleComponent1 extends React.Component {
    constructor = () => {
        super();
    }
}
```

webpack build failed:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError:....: 'super' outside of function or class (8:4)

I don't know why this happened, constructor can't declare as arrow function?

Comment: You cannot declare *any* `class` method as an arrow function in ES6. WTH are you trying to do? An assignment inside a class body is a syntax error.

Comment: What would you expect this transpile to? How should an arrow function (which can't be called with `new`) behave as a constructor (which can't be called without `new`)?

Comment: in arrow function, `super` (or `this`) refers to outer lexical scope chain. unless you use arrow function in regular function, it won't work as per spec. That is the main reason you are seeing this error

Comment: Arrow functions have no `this`, so it's not possible to use them in classes.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, functions can be maked using arrow but only if they are procedural or lambda functions !

Into class declarations, you are only allowed to use the standard ES6 syntax :

```
class ExampleComponent1 extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: An arrow function is never a declaration

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my post